# a bundle without options

Tags: products, bundled-product, grouped-products

We sell buttons (for the plug). Each of the buttons will cost 2,- Euro. A defined set of 3 buttons will cost 5,- EUR. All individual buttons are created as simple products. So far so good.

I have already tried a lot. The problems are:

- Grouped: The customer can define the number but the number is set).
- Bundle: compilation, the user can choose (but he should not) and the price is not unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to offer this defined set with its own product page, bundle products are the perfect fit.

To address your problems:

- When you create a bundle, you can choose to give it a fixed price instead of dynamic price, this means the price will not depend on the simple products.
- If you make the bundle options required and only add one selection per option, the user won't get to choose anything:

  - **Option 1**: Type "Checkbox", Required

    - Selection: Button 1
  - **Option 2**: Type "Checkbox", Required

    - Selection: Button 2
  - **Option 3**: Type "Checkbox", Required

    - Selection: Button 3

Answer (score 1):

If all the products are the same you can use tiered prices. If not, you can set promotions/discount rules to match a certain criteria.
Most of what you need might be [here.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_5)